# Passing delimited string to stored procedure to delete selected productIDs but deleted all data in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am grabbing the selected value from a dropdownlist that is populated with BrandNames. When the brand is selected it postbacks and calls a stored procedure to populate a checkbox list, which is products related to the selected BrandName.
Long story short when the user selects the products that he wants to delete, it gets populated in a delimited string and that and the BrandID is being passed to this stored procedure...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE s_RemoveProductsFromBrands
(
@BrandID int,
@TheProductIDs varchar(50)
)
as


-- Creating Variables
DECLARE @numberLength int
DECLARE @numberCount int
DECLARE @TheProducts varchar(200)
DECLARE @sTemp VarChar(100) -- to hold single characters

-- Creating a temp table
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(
TheProducts VarChar(500)
)
--Initializing Variables for counting 
SET @numberLength = LEN (@TheProductIDs)
SET @numberCount = 1
SET @TheProducts = ''

--Start looping through the keyword ids
WHILE (@numberCount <= @numberLength)

BEGIN
SET @sTemp = SUBSTRING (@TheProductIDs, @numberCount, 1)
    IF (@sTemp = ',')
        BEGIN
            INSERT @T(TheProducts) VALUES (@TheProducts)
            SET @TheProducts = ''
        END
    IF (@sTemp <> ',')
        BEGIN
            SET @TheProducts = @TheProducts + @sTemp
        END
        SET @numberCount = @numberCount + 1
END 

delete from [Products]

select TheProducts
from  @T
where TheProducts = TheProducts
```

I just ran this and I obviously made a mistake somewhere because I deleted all the products in my product table. Its a good thing I'm using a test database for this or else I'd be screwed from running the stored procedure that I wrote.

What I want to do is delete all Products that are related to the BrandID from the Brands table and a few others.

I use this stored procedure to add multiple products without any issue. So I figured that it would do the same thing but for deleting.

Any ideas on why all the products got wiped out when I executed this, and not the correct ProductID's?

Thanks

Comment: 4th line from bottom up 'delete from [Products]' caused deletion of the Products table

Comment: I see, so it should be like this 
delete ProductID from [Products]
where ProductID = TheProducts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read your question again and here is my edit

```
DELETE FROM [Products]
WHERE Products IN (SELECT TheProducts FROM @T)
```

**Your Code**

```
delete from [Products]   --<--- this Statement will delete all the records in your table

select TheProducts
from  @T
where TheProducts = TheProducts
```

Comment: But the thing is I need to delete all the ProductIDs that are being passed by delimited string. I use the BrandID to delete the products that are related to the BrandID..i.e BrandID 2, selects all products related to BrandID 2, user selects all products to delete from the BrandID 2

Comment: Yes I have read your question again and have updated my answer please have a look now.